# How to run C algorithm on Spark cluster?

Tags: c, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I have an algorithm that is written in C.

I want to use Spark to run it on a cluster of nodes. How can I run my C executable on Spark? I have read about JNI and Java Process to execute my binary.

Comment: I am not familiar with spark, but googling "running C code in spark" yields tons of results with answers, e.g., https://discourse.iscpif.fr/t/run-c-c-code-on-spark-yarn-cluster/473, Have you tried any smaller examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nice article from databricks on how we can run c and c++ codes in apache spark.

https://kb.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/scala/run-c-plus-plus-scala.html

After moving the c/c++ codes to the underlying distributed file system, You can compile the code and run on spark worker nodes.

Comment: Thanks you man! Now i read about Spark because i am new on the Spark ecosystem. When i finish, i will try this. Your provided article seems to be what i want. If you find similar articles please post it. Thank you again!

Comment: Sure.. if that clarifies your question - could you please mark it as answer ?

Comment: Sure, when i try it and if it works.